# "angular-bootstrap-md\index.ts is not part of the compilation output"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I wanted to use Angular-Bootstrap in my project, so I looked for a tutorial on how to download and install it, and get it to work on my computer. I'm using Visual Studio Code for this. I found a tutorial on how to do this, which is this one:

https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Angular-Bootstrap-with-Material-Design

I did every single step mentioned, but I get this weird error whenever I want to "ng start" or "ng build"; basically whenever I want to compile, I get this error:

```
bootstrap-weather@0.0.0 build C:\Users\Il\Desktop\WebFrameworks\Opdrachten\AngularBootstrapWeather\BootstrapWeather
> ng build

Date: 2017-11-07T16:19:07.296Z
Hash: d517558fb7e8e3484d3d
Time: 9269ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 8.17 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 200 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 465 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.29 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\Il\Desktop\WebFrameworks\Opdrachten\AngularBootstrapWeather\BootstrapWeather\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\index.ts is not part
 of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\Il\Desktop\WebFrameworks\Opdrachten\AngularBootstrapWeather\BootstrapWeather\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\an
gular_compiler_plugin.js:629:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\Il\Desktop\WebFrameworks\Opdrachten\AngularBootstrapWeather\BootstrapWeather\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 9:0-58
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Brackets\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Brackets\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bootstrap-weather@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap-weather@0.0.0 build script 'ng build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bootstrap-weather package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bootstrap-weather
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bootstrap-weather
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Il\Desktop\WebFrameworks\Opdrachten\AngularBootstrapWeather\BootstrapWeather\npm-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

It gives this weird error saying that "index.ts" is not part of the compilation... When I look at the "tsconfig.json" file of Angular-Bootstrap-Md itself, I see this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../../../../dist/angular-bootstrap-md/free",
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "inlineSources": true,
  "noEmitHelpers": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "declaration": true,
  "skipLibCheck": false,
  "stripInternal": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": false,
  "noUnusedParameters": false,
  "lib": ["dom", "es6"]
  },
  "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
  "./index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "../temp/factories",
  "strictMetadataEmit": true,
  "skipTemplateCodegen": true
  }
}
```

"Index.ts" is clearly included, as it is part of the "files" body. So, why does it say that it is not "part of the compilation", when it clearly is? And how do I fix this error so Bootstrap can finally function on my computer? And also, I don't know if this is worth mentioning, but my "app.module.ts" looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: i would write my point of view as an answer for u, but before that, please read this:
https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: No, I've never done that

Comment: I've never done cloning, rather I just installed through "npm install", and that's literally it. What's in the tutorial is what I did, nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Include this in `tsconfig.app.json`

```
"include": [

    "**/*.ts",

    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/index.ts"

  ],
```

or

just run by

```
ng serve --prod
```

Comment: The instructions in the 5-minute quickstart have this entry in the tsconfig.json.  Be aware that there is a bug in Angular 6 that requires the base path to be listed first, or you will get - ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.